# recurring HTML type mismatch

Tags: html, vba

this doesn't sound complicated but I am really struggling on understanding the issue here.

What is wrong in my code sample ? I tried to declare *collection_form* as different types but it only works as Variant, the type I want to avoid to work with since I need to get information from the children of the collection.

```
Dim collection_form As (see list below)
 'MsgBox TypeName(IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("ListMainCent")) ' returns  HTMLElementCollection

collection_form = IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("ListMainCent")
```

If I declare *collection_form* as the following types I get the following error :

1. As IHTMLElementCollection  - > Type Mismatch
2. As HTMLElementCollection  - > Run-time error '91' : Object variable or With block variable not set

Answer (score 1):

A collection is an object so you need `Set`

```
Set collection_form = IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("ListMainCent")
```